# Does this bowtie shaped digraph define a semilattice in the sense of Hasse diagram?

Tags: graph-theory, solution-verification, order-theory, semigroups

*I apologise for the bad formatting.*

### Motivation:

In my research, I have developed some ideas to do with semilattices. I regard them each as a set $L$ under an associative, commutative, idempotent binary operation; the distinction between meet and join semilattices is not yet relevant - they are isomorphic in the theory.

The diagram $(1)$ below was found in a picture somewhere in some search of semilattices, and trying to determine whether it is the Hasse diagram of a semilattice has given me a headache. I will attempt to explain why.

### The Question:

> Consider the directed graph
> $\require{AMScd}$
> $$\begin{CD} c & & d\\ @A t AA     \rlap{{_{\rlap{x}}\style{display: inline-block; transform: rotate(30deg)}{{\xleftarrow[\rule{2em}{0em}]{}}}}}{\style{display: inline-block; transform: rotate(150deg)}{{\xleftarrow[\rule{2em}{0em}]{}}}}{_{\llap{y}}} @AA z A\\ a & & b \end{CD}\tag{1}$$
>
> Does $(1)$ define a semilattice (in the sense of a [Hasse diagram](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hasse_diagram)?

### Thoughts:

Is the join $ab$ of $a$ and $b$ defined? Because both $c$ and $d$ are each greater than $a$ and $b$ (via $\{t,y\}$ for $c$ and $\{ x,z\}$ for $d$) and have no intermediaries (so to speak), yet they are distinct. If $\{ a,b,c,d\}$ were a semilattice, then, my confusion has it, $c=ab=d$ while $c\neq d$, a contradiction to the fact that concatenation here is a binary operation!

Yet the source (I lost) has it that it *does* define a semilattice.

Perhaps I should trust random documents I can't find again less than my poor intuition in the area. But maybe my proof is wrong . . .

### Where do I think it's wrong?

My guess is the step $c=ab=d$. Does it make sense to speak of *the* join? This feels like a restatement of the contradiction of the proof though . . .

Comment: You are correct. It doesn't define a semi-lattice. If some say it does, there must be some other construction going on there.

Comment: A finite lattice has a minimum and a maximum. This order has neither

Comment: I'm after a semilattice, @Jakobian. But thank you.

Comment: @Shaun Every semilattice $(S, \cdot)$ introduces a unique lattice structure on $S$ for which $a\cdot b = a\vee b$ is the join. Thus when thinking about them as orders, we are free to drop the semi- prefix.